# iCloud Core Data 2018

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, icloud

I have an iOS application written in Swift with Xcode 9 that stores objects locally with Core Data. I would now like to apply iCloud sync to this app such that a single user can access and modify this data across multiple devices, though I am not sure where to begin. I have searched much but it remains unclear to me if "iCloud CoreData" works anymore or if CloudKit is ideal.

What would be the best approach to this today? Could someone perhaps direct me to a modern example/documentation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: iCloud Core Data is deprecated but still works. From my experience it’s pretty easy but not very reliable especially when syncing over different platforms. CloudKit is state of the art, it’s very robust but not trivial to implement. Again from my personal experience the best CloudKit documentation are the WWDC videos and the Apple documentation.